# DropDownList loses value after processing page

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have a field of type **activeDropDownList** where the user selects the desired month and the view "mobilizer" process a lot of query with selected month.

However after rendering the page the field **activeDropDownList** loses the value. (Returns to the prompt value `'prompt'=>'Selecione o mês'`).

```
<?php 

    $this->registerJs('var submit = function (val){if (val > 0) {
        window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['dailyproductivity/mobilizador']) . '&mes=" + val;
    }
    }', View::POS_HEAD);
    echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'mes', app\modules\productivity\models\Meta::getFiltroMes(), ['onchange'=>'submit(this.value);','prompt'=>'Selecione o mês','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'style' => 'text-transform: uppercase']);
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**

In my model `Meta.php`

```
public static function getFiltroMes()
    {
        $data = [
            '01' => 'JANEIRO',
            '02' => 'FEVEREIRO',
            '03' => 'MARÇO',
            '04' => 'ABRIL',
            '05' => 'MAIO',
            '06' => 'JUNHO',
            '07' => 'JULHO',
            '08' => 'AGOSTO',
            '09' => 'SETEMBRO',
            '10' => 'OUTUBRO',
            '11' => 'NOVEMBRO',
            '12' => 'DEZEMBRO',
        ];

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Try checking if there is correct value in `$model->mes` for example by using `echo $model->mes;` right before the `Html::activeDropDownList`.

Comment: seems you are refreshing the page or sending it on some other action, so the value of your field $model->mes is empty again.

Comment: The  `echo $model->mes;` displays correct value

Comment: @gugoan And what is "correct value"? Can you show result of `var_dump($model->mes)`?

Comment: @rob006 My post was not correct, `var_dump($model->mes)` content is NULL

Comment: are you saying that once you select an option from the dropdown and the page submits, you loose the value from the dropdown after view loads again ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the javasript code and change `&` to `?` in the url query string, which is the reason your `$model->mes` is `null` because the querystring wasnt appended

```
'&mes=" + val;
```

to

```
'?mes=" + val;
```

so that the line looks like

```
window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['dailyproductivity/mobilizador']) . '?mes=" + val;
```

You should use HEREDOC when you need to add the javascript snippets in the view via php so that the readability helps you to spot the errors yourself

Your code should look like below

```
$js=<<<JS
    var submit = function (val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['dailyproductivity/mobilizador']) . '?mes=" + val;
        }
    }
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, View::POS_HEAD);
```